# Curious closed forms of the $q$-Gamma function.

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, closed-form, infinite-product, q-analogs

I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gamma_function) the $q$-Gamma function, defined as 
$$\Gamma_q(x)=(1-q)^{1-x}\prod_{n\ge0}\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q^{n+x}}$$
for $|q|<1$. There is a definition for $|q|>1$, but we won't need that here (I think).

The page also provided me with some curious results. For brevity, we define
$$j(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac14)}\Gamma_{e^{-\pi z}}(\tfrac12).$$
Then Wikipedia tells me that
$$\begin{align}
j(1)&=\frac{\sqrt{e^\pi-1}\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt2}}{2^{15/16}\pi^{3/4}e^{7\pi/16}}\\
j(2)&=\frac{\sqrt{e^{2\pi}-1}}{2^{9/8}\pi^{3/4}e^{7\pi/8}}\\
j(4)&=\frac{\sqrt{e^{4\pi}-1}}{2^{7/4}\pi^{3/4}e^{7\pi/4}}\\
j(8)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{e^{8\pi}-1}}{2^{9/4}\pi^{3/4}e^{7\pi/2}}.
\end{align}$$

**Can anyone prove these?**
As some of you may know, my experience lies in the evaluation of integrals and infinite series, and I have very little experience or knowledge when it comes to infinite products. That being said, please forgive me when I do not include any attempts, as I genuinely have no idea where to start. The purpose of this question is to not only see proofs for these fascinating identities but to also to learn techniques for evaluating infinite products in general.

---

**Edit**

I found on Wikipedia the series
$$\frac{(q;q)_\infty}{(z;q)_\infty}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nq^{n(n+1)/2}}{(q;q)_n(1-zq^n)}\qquad |z|<1$$
where 
$$(a;q)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k).$$
Anyway, we can see that 
$$\Gamma_q(\tfrac12)=(1-q)^{1/2}\frac{(q;q)_\infty}{(q^{1/2};q)_\infty}=(1-q)^{1/2}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^kq^{k(k+1)/2}}{(q;q)_k(1-q^{k+1/2})},$$
but that really doesn't help me that much, to be honest.

Comment: Curiously, the linked paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1042.pdf doesn't seem to contain the above formulas, even though it's listed as the source of them. They probably follow from some general result there

Comment: As for your last paragraph, infinite products of numbers can be treated by the same methods as infinite series, if you take the logarithm. Infinite products of matrices are more complicated, but this is not the case here

Comment: See very similar cases of closed form for theta functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Explicit_values

Comment: We have: $$\log \Gamma_q(1/2)= \frac{1}{2} \log (1-q)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}  \frac{q^{k/2}}{1+q^{k/2}}$$ This explains at least one factor in the provided closed forms

Comment: This question belongs to realm of modular forms and complex multiplication rather than $q$-analogs. It all boils down to $\eta(\tau)^2/\eta(\tau/2)$, or equivalently, value of $\vartheta_2$ when $\tau = ni$. For all $n$, they are effectively computable, but the algorithm, as well as explaining why it work, is not elementary.

Comment: The method for evaluating $\eta(in)/\eta(i)$ is quite the same as the one for evaluating $j(in)$ (the j-invariant) from the theory of elliptic curves with complex multiplication https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/LectureNotes21.pdf we obtain the minimal polynomials of $\eta(in)/\eta(i)$ and because they generate abelian extensions they are radical (their roots have closed-forms in term of $k$-th roots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Introduction.** The [$\Gamma_q$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-GammaFunction.html) is a [$q$-analog](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Analog.html) of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) defined by
$$
\Gamma_q(x) = \frac{(q;q)_\infty}{\left(q^x;q\right)_\infty}(1-q)^{1-x},\quad |q|<1,
$$
where $(a;q)_\infty$ is a [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html).

[Ramanujan's $\psi$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanPsi-Function.html) defined by
$$
\psi(q)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{n(n+1)/2} = \frac{\left(q^2;q^2\right)_\infty}{\left(q;q^2\right)_\infty},
$$
where the infinite product representation arises from the [Jacobi triple product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html) identity.

We can express $\Gamma_{q}\left(1/2\right)$ in terms of the $\psi$ function as the following:
$$
\Gamma_q\left(\frac12\right) = \psi\left(\sqrt{q}\right)\sqrt{1-q}.
$$
The $\psi$ function and related functions $-$ so-called [Ramanujan's theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanThetaFunctions.html) $-$ are widely studied in Berndt's [*Ramanujan's Notebooks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_C._Berndt#Selected_publications). We summarize here the relevant parts, and refer to Berndt for details.

**Values of Ramanujan's $\psi$ function.** For $0 < x < 1$, let
$$
z = {_2}F{_1}\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;x\right)
$$
and
$$
y = \pi \frac{{_2}F{_1}\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;1-x\right)}{{_2}F{_1}\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;x\right)},
$$
where ${_2}F{_1}$ is the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

We have 
\begin{align}
\psi\left(e^{-y/4}\right) &= \sqrt{z}\left(1+x^{1/4}\right)^{1/2}\left(\tfrac12 \left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)\right)^{1/8}\left(xe^y\right)^{1/32},\tag{1}\\
\psi\left(e^{-y/2}\right) &= \sqrt{z}\left(\tfrac12 \left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)\right)^{1/4}\left(xe^y\right)^{1/16},\tag{2}\\
\psi\left(e^{-y}\right) &= \sqrt{\tfrac12 z}\left(xe^y\right)^{1/8},\tag{3}\\
\psi\left(e^{-2y}\right) &= \tfrac12 \sqrt{z} \left(xe^y\right)^{1/4},\tag{4}\\
\psi\left(e^{-4y}\right) &= \tfrac12 \sqrt{\tfrac12 z}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{1-x}\right)e^y\right)^{1/2},\tag{5}\\
\psi\left(e^{-8y}\right) &= \tfrac14\sqrt{z}\left(1-\left(1-x\right)^{1/4}\right)e^y.\tag{6}
\end{align}

The notation for $z$ and $y$ are defined in Berndt [Part $\text{III}$, p. $101$, Entry $6$, $(6.2)$ and $(6.3)$]. The formulas $(1)\!-\!(6)$ are given with proof in Berndt [Part $\text{III}$, p. $123$, Entry $11$.].

**Values of $y$ and $z$ for $x = 1/2$.** It is clear that $y = \pi$ for $x = 1/2$. To evaluate $z$, we use the following [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0025.01), which is given in Berndt [Part $\text{III}$, p. $89$, $(1.4)$]. If $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary, then
$$
{_2}F{_1}\left(a,b;\tfrac12 \left(a + b + 1\right);\tfrac12\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac12\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac12 \left(a + b + 1\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac12 + \tfrac12 a\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac12 + \tfrac12 b\right)}.
$$
In particular, if $c$ is arbitrary, then
$$
{_2}F{_1}\left(1 - c,c;1;\tfrac12\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(1 - \tfrac12 c\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac12 + \tfrac12 c\right)}.
$$
For $c = 1/2$, we have
$$
z = {_2}F{_1}\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12;1;\tfrac12\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac12\right)}{\Gamma^2\left(\tfrac34\right)} = \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{\Gamma^2\left(\tfrac34\right)} = \frac{\Gamma^2\left(\tfrac14\right)}{2\pi^{3/2}},
$$
where we used the [particular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers) $\Gamma\left(\tfrac12\right) = \sqrt{\pi}$ and the [product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Products) $\Gamma\left(\tfrac14\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac34\right) = \sqrt{2}\pi$.

> **Values of $\Gamma_q\left(1/2\right)$.** Let 
>   $$
> a = \frac{\pi^{1/4}}{\Gamma\left(3/4\right)}.
> $$
>   Then
>   \begin{align}
> \Gamma_{e^{-\pi/2}}\left(\tfrac12\right) &= a2^{-11/32}\left(2^{1/4}+1\right)^{1/2}\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)^{1/8}e^{\pi/32}\sqrt{1-e^{-\pi/2}},\tag{1'}\\
> \Gamma_{e^{-\pi}}\left(\tfrac12\right) &= 
> a2^{-7/16}\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)^{1/4}e^{\pi/16}\sqrt{1-e^{-\pi}},\tag{2'}\\
> \Gamma_{e^{-2\pi}}\left(\tfrac12\right) &= a2^{-5/8}e^{\pi/8}\sqrt{1-e^{-2\pi}},\tag{3'}\\
> \Gamma_{e^{-4\pi}}\left(\tfrac12\right) &= a2^{-5/4}e^{\pi/4}\sqrt{1-e^{-4\pi}},\tag{4'}\\
> \Gamma_{e^{-8\pi}}\left(\tfrac12\right) &= a2^{-2}\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^{1/2}e^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-e^{-8\pi}},\tag{5'}\\
> \Gamma_{e^{-16\pi}}\left(\tfrac12\right) &= a2^{-2}\left(1-2^{-1/4}\right)e^{\pi}\sqrt{1-e^{-16\pi}}.\tag{6'}
> \end{align}

The values of the $\psi$ function that is corresponding to the formulas $(1\text{'})\!-\!(6\text{'})$ are given in Berndt [Part $\text{V}$, p. $325$, Entry $1$.].

Comment: Brilliant (+1). Where did you learn all of this amazing stuff? I absolutely love analytic number theory/speial functions.

Comment: @clathratus Thank you. Mostly by myself from books.

Comment: You should mention about Landen transformation which allows us to half or double the value of $y$. Let the relation between $y$ and $x$ be denoted by $y=f(x) $ then $$f(x) =2f\left(\frac{4\sqrt{x}}{(1+\sqrt {x}) ^2}\right)$$ and we get another relation obtained by inverting this namely $$2f(x)=f\left(\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}\right) ^2\right)$$

Comment: @clathratus: there are similar formulas for the relation between $z$ and $x$, say given by $z=g(x) $ with $$g\left(\frac{4\sqrt{x}}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}\right)=(1+\sqrt {x}) g(x) $$ and $$g\left(\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)^2\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{2}g(x)$$